# Previous commit info of all git repo's used in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline which checkout several git repos. I want to retrieve the commit id for all repos used in a previous successful Jenkins build. I tried using `env.GIT_COMMIT` but that points to the commit id of the pipeline. Is there any way of retrieving all commit ids used during a pipeline run.

```
stages {
        stage('Checkout RepoA') {
            steps {
                dir("${runDir}/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/checkout") {
                    checkout(
                        [
                            $class: 'GitSCM',
                                branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/main']],
                                extensions: [
                                    [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'RepoA'],
                                    [$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: 'main']
                                ],
                                userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'credentials', url: 'url to repo']]
                        ]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a very specific and unusual need. Is it feasible to include a build step which records that kind of information to a log or database that you could query in subsequent builds?

Comment: it makes sense to want it, but you'll have to find some way of enumerating the repos involved and then you can get their commit sha in various ways

Comment: How are you checking out? Can you add a minimal sample Pipeline?